# Angular database in local

Tags: database, angular

Good evening,
I would like to create a web application with angular 6 but I do not have all the time access to the internet connection (my application needs a database and everything). I saw that we could do it with firebase but its need to have all the time access to intertnet, Can I create a CRUD application with local database

Comment: Check this article - https://medium.com/jsstore/using-jsstore-in-angular-448333e91421 . It is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For Web application, you can use IndexedDB Database storage mechanism which will support unlimited storage. You can use LocalForage Storage Service released by Mozilla. It has a fallback to WebSQL if your browser doesn't support IndexedDB. Its a NoSQL DB Storage.

It also contains Angular Utility service for Local Forage. Ionic Also supports LocalForage using Ionic Storage.

https://github.com/localForage/localForage

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the http interceptor to check if you are connected to internet, and if not, save data to local storage. When you reconnect you should synchronize your local storage with your web database. You can put a button also to run synchronize process and mark data in UI with a status indicator.

This task of synchronizing can be easy, doable or extremely difficult depending on the logic of your data. If you could give us more details on what you are planning to do, we can give you better advice.